# Import CSV directly into ListObject

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have a CSV file that I want to get imported into an table (i.e. a ListObject).

Normally I'd do this with Data->Import text file ... - and then convert the result to a Table. However, this breaks the connection, i.e. the user cannot simply press refresh and gets the updated data into the table.

I know I could do it with VBA (via the same way, i.e. importing the data and then creating the listobject), but this would still break the connection.

Is there any way to import CSV data into a listObject without breaking the connection?

I tried

```
Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
    Source:="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=filename.csv;Extended Properties=Text;", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

but this only produced a 1004 error.

Comment: I think that as a source you should use `Recordset Object`, not `ConnectionString (text)`. However, I think this will not allow to refresh LO, unfortunately. But you could try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question Peter. Today I was faced with the same issue and, thanks to Charley Kid at ExcelUser.com, found what seems like the best solution.

This is going to verge on a link-only answer, but the summary is that you can get this by using MS Query. To start click on DATA>From Other Sources>From Microsoft Query.

This method creates an schema.ini file for as many text files as you have in a folder. So basically the folder is your database and the text files are your tables. Once this file was created by the MS Query wizard, I found it much easier to modify in a text editor. And again, you can define the import schema for all the text files in a folder.

Here's the [Charley Kid post](http://exceluser.com/formulas/msquery-excel-text-files.htm). I had to read through it a couple of times before I got the finicky details right.

And here's a link to an [MS page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with details on the schema.ini setup.

If you have time to look into it, I'd appreciate your thoughts, as I'm planning to use it in a fairly big project.

Comment: Thanks Doug! This looks like the right approach, I really like it (though way too complicated - why doesn't Excel support this natively?!). Won't be able to test for the next week though... :-/